# Визуализация в matplotlib при работе с датафреймом

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Когда открываю таблицу с помощью:

```
df = pd.read_excel('rosn.xlsx')
df.head()
```

получаю такую таблицу(рис 1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

рисую график:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Close'])
plt.title('Цена закрытия акций Роснефть.', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Стоимость, руб.')
plt.show()
```

и получаю (рис 2).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда я сразу преобразовываю формат даты:

```
df = pd.read_excel('rosn.xlsx', parse_dates=["Date"])
```

я получаю нужный формат даты (datetime64[ns]), но выходит вот такой график.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, можно ли сделать нормальный график, когда формат даты "datetime64[ns]", а не "object"?

Comment: Мне кажется, скорее всего при парсинге дат путаются местами день и месяц. Не факт, но как вариант. Попробуйте задать конкретный `date_format` в параметрах. А вообще не могли бы вы куда-то файл с данными выложить, чтобы мы могли попробовать его загрузить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_excel('rosn.xlsx', parse_dates=["Date"])
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```